# Setting different color for material UI range slider's thumbs

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, slider, rangeslider

Hi I am building a range slider with 2 values using material UI slider component and I am trying to make the two thumbs have different colors.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit hacky but it accomplishes what you desire.

Essentially, you want to make use to MaterialUI's `useStyle` to create a custom style, and then select the thumb elements via reference of their child index.

Because the thumbs are predictably the 4th and 5th element in a ranged slider, you can select them with some CSS and style them accordingly:

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { Slider, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export default function StyledSlider() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([20, 37]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      "&>.MuiSlider-thumb": {
        "&:nth-child(4)": {
          color: "green !important"
        },
        "&:nth-child(5)": {
          color: "red !important"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        Example Slider
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        aria-labelledby="range-slider"
        className={classes.root}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-66666691-muithumbs-4s3rh?file=/src/StyledSlider.jsx:0-900

References:

- [`useStyle` docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

Using MUI v. 5.10, I achieved it with a styled component:

```
import { Slider as MuiSlider, styled } from '@mui/material';

const Slider = styled(MuiSlider)({
  '& .MuiSlider-thumb[data-index="0"]': {
    color: 'green',
  },
  '& .MuiSlider-thumb[data-index="1"]': {
    color: 'purple',
  },
});
```

That code gives

[image]